# SkyVector zoom levels vs. rest of the world

Tags: tiles, zoom, hyperlink, url

Has anybody ever figured out the, <del>crazy backwards</del> unconventional zoom levels on [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/)?
All I'm trying to do is make the equivalent hyperlink for, say, an [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) hyperlink.
Why does it have to be such a mind-numbing adventure?

Answer (score 1):

Calm down. Patient observation would have shown you the **only** correspondences are:

- **OSM:SV**:
- [1](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=1/46/-85):[21](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=21)
- [2](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=2/46/-85):[19](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=19)
- [3](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=3/46/-85):[17](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=17)
- [4](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/46/-85):[15](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=15)
- [5](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/46/-85):[13](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=13)
- [6](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=6/46/-85):[11](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=11)
- [7](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/46/-85):[9](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=9)
- [8](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/46/-85):[7](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=7)
- [9](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=9/46/-85):[5](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=5)
- [10](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/46/-85):[3](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=3)
- [11](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/46/-85):[1](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&zoom=1).

I.e.,

- OSM = ( 23 - SV ) / 2
- SV = 23 - ( 2 * OSM )

but **only** for the legitimate zoom levels.

And we're talking desktop versus desktop. Once mobile enters the picture things get different..

Indeed the same logic even permeates down to the zoom (Z) parameter of the [tile numbers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect that has not been explored is there are different zoom levels for different layers for the **same coverage**!

The 23 - (2 * OSM) only holds for the default layer,

https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=7

22 - (2 * OSM):

https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=6

20 - (2 * OSM):

https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=4

And that's just a few of the layers on that site.

Thus we now see why people post various solutions for SkyVector linking that just don't seem to be accurate.

They're only looking at one layer, and we are looking at another! Yes. Nobody has ever encountered anything like this so we can't blame them.

Anyway all we are trying to do is just get an equivalent link. Something any normal law abiding citizen would want to do. Yes and we finally succeeded. (Fingers crossed.)

Alright. So we need to expand the list in the other (split personality) person's answer, to a table:

| OSM | 301 | 302 | 304 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=1/46/-85) | [21](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=21) | [20](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=20) | [18](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=18) |
| [2](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=2/46/-85) | [19](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=19) | [18](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=18) | [16](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=16) |
| [3](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=3/46/-85) | [17](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=17) | [16](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=16) | [14](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=14) |
| [4](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/46/-85) | [15](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=15) | [14](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=14) | [12](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=12) |
| [5](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/46/-85) | [13](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=13) | [12](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=12) | [10](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=10) |
| [6](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=6/46/-85) | [11](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=11) | [10](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=10) | [8](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=8) |
| [7](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/46/-85) | [9](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=9) | [8](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=8) | [6](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=6) |
| [8](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/46/-85) | [7](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=7) | [6](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=6) | [4](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=4) |
| [9](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=9/46/-85) | [5](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=5) | [4](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=4) | [2](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=304&zoom=2) |
| [10](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/46/-85) | [3](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=3) | [2](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=302&zoom=2) |  |
| [11](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/46/-85) | [1](https://skyvector.com/?ll=46,-85&chart=301&zoom=1) |  |  |

Sure, on the website one can keep clicking the "+" button, and the map will keep zooming. But going below 1 won't get any fresh map tiles. It will just zoom the ones already in your browser. (And OSM can go to 0, but SkyVector is already maxed out at OSM's 1.)

And yes, we note a `23 + 301 - $chart - ( 2 * OSM)` relationship! (For these tip of the iceberg charts at least.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you also asked about the rest of the world, regarding those unmatched intermediate SkyVector zoom levels, [Google Maps x.5 zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/vector-map#fractional-zoom)
surely correspond to SkyVector levels 2, 4, 6...

- **GG** : **SV**:
- 1.5 : 20
- ...
- 10.5 : 2.

Alas, it might not be possible to give nice clickable pairs, due to API whole number [requirements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#parameters_1).